# How to get a GitHub App access token via shell

Tags: github, github-app

Given an app id and secret (pem), how can I get an access token for a repo my app is installed at via a shell script?

Answer (score 4):

This [script](https://gist.github.com/987Nabil/594764a7444cb5eee0636607d06f43c5) is what you are looking for. It uses only `open-ssl`, `jq` and `curl`.
You can either get a token only for a given repo or all repos the app is installed to.